# Update Access table from Excel- says current record has been deleted?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, sql-update

Basically I've got some code here that updates Access from Excel, it does this via seeing if the 'Monitoring ID' equals the 'IngID' which is essentially the Monitoring ID. So basically if they match, the code needs will update the field in the access table marked 'TOWN'.

However when I do this I get an error at `.Fields("TOWN") = Cells(lngRow, 74).Value`. The error being: "Run-time error 3021 Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record." 
The record does exist in the table and I have tried with multiple however it still doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim MyConn
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngID, LR, Upd
Dim sSQL As String

LR = Range("BN" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Upd = LR - 1

lngRow = 1
Do While lngRow <= LR


lngID = Cells(lngRow, 66).Value


sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Primary WHERE MonitorID = '" & lngID & "'"


Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

MyConn = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source =location of access file.mdb"
With cnn

.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.Open MyConn

End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.Open sSQL, ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

'Load all records from Excel to Access.


With rst
'
.Fields("TOWN") = Cells(lngRow, 74).Value


rst.Update
End With

' Close the connection
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

lngRow = lngRow + 1

Loop
MsgBox "Update Complete"
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** This is not the issue.

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Primary WHERE MonitorID = '" & lngID & "'"
```

If `MonitorID` is a number, the ' don't belong there, you only need them for strings.
So:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Primary WHERE MonitorID = " & lngID
```

Although I'm not sure it will solve the issue, unfortunately Jet is rather forgiving with these kind of mistakes.

Comment: That's the problem it isn't a number, although each is unique it includes letters also at the end, so for example it might be 16SC as an ID.

Comment: Okay, so you named the variable `lngID` (as in "Long") for maximum confusion? :-)  @Calum

Comment: Ha ha sorry, I've tried as String and no luck either. :( @Andre451

Comment: Nevertheless, please edit your question and name the variable `strID` so that other people won't stumble over the same thing.  @Calum

Comment: Sorry @Andre451, I got confused I haven't tried that as a string- do you know how I would change it for this? simply changing to `StrID` won't be the fix will it?

Comment: No, it won't solve anything. But it is a widely used naming convention for variables: `lngVar` is of type Long, `strVar` or `sVar` is of type String. Now if you use `lngID`, everybody thinks that it must be of datatype Long. But it isn't. So everybody is confused. Just change the variable name in your code to `StrID`. And declare it `As String` while you're at it. It helps readibility.